# How do I force close a tag in jade templates?

Tags: pug

How do you force close a tag in jade? This may be a be a bad example, but If i wanted to put a div in between the `</head>` & `<body>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write HTML in your jade

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  <head></head>
  body jade again
```

But you cannot put jade into your `head` elements, so when you start using HTML you cannot mix its content and children with jade.

Comment: I didn't need to put an &amp; i just needed to put something there. It has to do with a particular js library. Off the top of my head i can't remember, but this worked!

Comment: if you (downvoter) are doing this then at least provide a reason

Comment: @timaschew The answer does not address the full question, which involved placing an element in between the head and body tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to put something like `<div class="your-content"></div>` between the `body` and `head`, you don't need to resort to plain html. Instead:

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")

  head
    ...more pug/jade...

  .your-content
    ...more pug/jade...

  body
    ...more pug/jade...
```