# HTML5 Context Menu with Pug

Tags: node.js, html, pug

There currently appears to be a bug in Pug/Jade, in which `<menuitem>` is treated as self-closing, when in reality, they need to be closed. I've submitted the issue to the GitHub repo, and am awaiting a response/fix, but in the meantime, is there a viable alternative?

This is my **contextmenu.pug** file:

```
menu#main(type="context", label="")
    menu(label="Visit me on...")
        menuitem(label="LinkedIn")
        menuitem(label="Twitter")
        menuitem(label="Github")
        menuitem(label="Stack Overflow")
        menuitem(label="Email")
    menuitem(label="Go Home")
```

The HTML is rendered as:

```
<menu id="main" type="context" label="">
    <menu label="Visit me on...">
        <menuitem label="LinkedIn">
        <menuitem label="Twitter">
        <menuitem label="Github">
        <menuitem label="Stack Overflow">
        <menuitem label="Email">
    </menu>
    <menuitem label="Go Home">
</menu>
```

Whereas, I would like all the `menuitem` tags to close with a `</menuitem>`. Otherwise, this would cause LinkedIn to be the only option that appears under "Visit me on..." The closest example I could find to this was [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25650988/how-do-i-force-close-a-tag-in-jade-templates), which suggested using plain HTML, and while this works, I am wondering if there is a Pug-only alternative. Is there a setting somewhere that determines which tags are self-closing? Or has there been a better alternative to forcing a closing tag since that question?

In case it matters, I'm using the Express.js framework, and recently updated from Jade (The issue existed before the migration).

[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2664)

Answer (score 0):

You can write the `menuitem`s as plaintext:

```
menu#main(type="context", label="")
  menu(label="Visit me on...").
    <menuitem label="LinkedIn"></menuitem>
    <menuitem label="Twitter"></menuitem>
    <menuitem label="Github"></menuitem>
    <menuitem label="Stack Overflow"></menuitem>
    <menuitem label="Email"></menuitem>
    <menuitem label="Go Home"></menuitem>
```

https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip, but I'm specifically trying to avoid this method.